# Accessing json objects with jquery arrays

Tags: jquery, json

I have JSON data in this format:

```js
{
  "head": {
    "heading": ["header1", "header2", "header3"]
  },
  "body": {
    "elements": [{
        "header1": {
          "value": "value1"
        },
        "header2": {
          "value": "value2"
        }
        "header3": {
          "value": "value3"
        }
      },
      {
        "header1": {
          "value": "value1"
        },
        "header2": {
          "value": "value2"
        }
        "header3": {
          "value": "value3"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

I can't predict the number of values in headings. So, I initially parsed the values in headings and stored in an array. Later while printing the body elements. I wrote the following code

```
// data has the parsed json file
var heading = [];
data.head.heading.forEach(function(head) {
  heading.push(head);
});
data.body.elements.forEach( function(elem) {
  for (var head in the heading) {
    var header = heading[head];
    alert(elem.header.value); //not accessing value inside header
  }
});
```

On using `values.header.value` it needs to access value inside `header1`, `header2` and `header3` of each elem but it is returning an error

> TypeError: elem.header is undefined

It is taking the value as the header instead of value inside the variable header. Is there any way to make it access the values inside the variable header? thanks in advance

Comment: element.header won't ever exist as they're named `header1, 2, 3`.  You'll need to run trough `Object.keys`.

Comment: header consists of values of array heading. It actually consist of values header1, heaader2 and heaader3 for each turn

Comment: seeing this the first time ´ for (var x in the y´s )´

Comment: Because header contains the key value you can change from **elem.header.value** to **elem[header].value**. At the same time your foreach is: data.body.elements.forEach

Comment: @gaetanoM thanks for the reply. But I can't exactly understand what you said. Can you be more specific? thanks

Comment: @SandeshGhanta See the Roy's answer. That's it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access the object using bracket notation as the value of `header` needs to be used as the key, not the literal word 'header`, eg.

```
elem[header].value
```

Also, your first loop is entirely redundant, as you're just copying an array you already have access to. Try this:

```
data.body.elements.forEach(function(elem) {
  for (var head in data.head.heading) {
    var header = data.head.heading[head];
    console.log(elem[header].value);
  }
});
```

Finally, note that this can be made even more succinct by using another nested `forEach()` call to iterate `data.head.heading`:

```js
var data = {
  "head": {
    "heading": ["header1", "header2", "header3"]
  },
  "body": {
    "elements": [{
      "header1": { "value": "value1" },
      "header2": { "value": "value2" },
      "header3": { "value": "value3" }
    },
    {
      "header1": { "value": "value1" },
      "header2": { "value": "value2" },
      "header3": { "value": "value3" }
    }]
  }
}

data.body.elements.forEach(function(elem) {
  data.head.heading.forEach(function(header) {
    console.log(elem[header].value);
  });
});
```